# function differentiability of $g(x)=|f(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, alternative-proof

$1.$ Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is diferentiable at $c$ and that $f(c)=0$. Show that $g(x):=|f(x)|$ is diferentiable at $c$ if and only if $f'(c)=0$.

$Proof.\Leftarrow      $   Suppose that $f'(c)=0$ , then as $f$ is differentiable at $c$, we've got that:
Let $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $\delta>0$ such that $x\in B_{\delta}(c)$ then:

$||\frac{f(c+h)}{h}|-|f'(c)||\leq |\frac{f(c+h)}{h}-f'(c)|<\varepsilon$, by hypothesis $f'(c)=0$, thus;

$\left | \frac{|f(c+h)|}{|h|} \right |<\varepsilon$, hence $g(x)$ is differentiable at $c$.

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose that $g(x):=|f(x)|$ is diferentiable at $c$, and suppose $f'(c)\not= 0$, then:

$g'(c)=lim_{x\to c}\frac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}=lim_{x \to c}\frac{|f(x)|-|f(c)|}{x-c}=lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(c+h)|}{|h|} $.

**case 1.** If $f'(c)>0$.

I have tried to reason for contradiction in this last implication, but I am not sure, I would like to receive a suggestion.

Comment: If $f'(c)\neq 0$ there is a neighborhood of $c$ where $f$ assumes positive and negative values.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that if $f'(c)>0$, then, there exist $B_{\delta}(c)$, hence $\frac{f(x)}{x-c}>0$, 
but I don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $g'(c)$ exists. Then, since $f(c)=0$, the limit
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(c+h)|}{h}$$
exists too. Call it $\alpha$. Clearly, the right-side limit is non-negative:
$$\lim_{h\to 0,h\geq 0}\frac{|f(c+h)|}{h}\geq 0$$
so $\alpha\geq 0$. Clearly, the left-side limit is non-positive:
$$\lim_{h\to 0,h\leq 0}\frac{|f(c+h)|}{h}\leq 0$$
hence $\alpha\leq 0$. So $\alpha$ must be zero. That is, $g'(c)=0$. This immediately implies that $f'(c)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If f'(c)>0, f is an incresing function and f(c)=0 $\Rightarrow$ f(c-h)<0 and f(c+h)>0

LHD g'($c^-)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(c-h)|-|f(c)|}{-h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(c-h)|}{-h}$

g'($c^-)=\lim_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{-f(c-h)}{-h}=\lim_{h \to 0} -\frac{f(c-h)-f(c)}{-h}$=-f'($c$)

RHD g'($c^+)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(c+h)|-|f(c)|}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(c+h)|}{h}$

g'($c^-)=\lim_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{f(c+h)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$=f'($c$)

Since, f'(c)$\ne$0 $\Rightarrow LHD \ne RHD$

Similarly, we can repeat the process for f'(c)<0